# PDO Oracle Driver PHP 7.4 Nginx

Tags: php, oracle, pdo, driver

I am facing an issue with PDO Oracle Driver PHP 7.4 Nginx, I am not getting a proper solution or instruction on how to install that, can anyone please help

### Code

```
try {
    $conn = new PDO('oci:dbname=//development.czeika65wu6y.us-east-1.rds.amazonaws.com:1521/xe/ORCL', 'xxxx', 'xxxxx');
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
    } catch(PDOException $e) {
       echo 'ERROR: ' . $e->getMessage();
    }
```

Getting ERROR: could not find driver

Comment: Have you uncommented it in your php.ini?  Do you need to install the package containing it?  Or build it from source code?